# PHP doesnt display anything

Tags: php, android, json

Hi guys I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to display all info in my admin table. When I test my PHP file it gives me a blank page, here is my php code. There's no error but I get a blank page and nothing was returned when I execute it.

```
 <?php

require('connect.inc.php');
require('admin.config.inc.php');
require('core.inc.php');

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    //initial query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin where username = :user";

    $query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username']);

    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt = $db -> prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt -> execute($query_params);
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
    $rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();

    if ($rows) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
        $response["users"] = array();

        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $user = array();
            $user["username"] = $row["username"];
            $user["designation"] = $row["designation"];
            $user["middlename"] = $row["middle_initial"];
            $user["firstname"] = $row["first_name"];
            $user["lastname"] = $row["last_name"];

            //update our repsonse JSON data
            array_push($response["users"], $user);
        }

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No user available!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

} else {}


       ?>
```

Comment: Put few more 'echo' and 'message' in between your blocks to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe you ran into `else` statement I guess.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST))` is not true unless there are POST values.

Comment: add some else condition 'echo'

Comment: I solved it already thanks though:)

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the head of the script to see what response you get. Then others may be able to help you according to the error you get.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I see you have also began with:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

}
```

$_POST IS An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

$_POST is defined where. this should be some thing like $_POST['user']

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `$user = array();` inside the loop, It has to be outside of the loop

```
$user = array();

foreach($rows as $row) {           
            $user["username"] = $row["username"];
            $user["designation"] = $row["designation"];
            $user["middlename"] = $row["middle_initial"];
            $user["firstname"] = $row["first_name"];
            $user["lastname"] = $row["last_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You begin with:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
```

which is empty by default, so you go directly to the else statement which is empty as well!